# Best way to maintain counts of objects

Tags: c#, collections

I have a set of objects (say they are all different kinds of animals --- Bear, Bear, Lion, Tiger, Bear)

What is the best way to maintain a count for each animal?

I tried to use Dictionary but the "int" is of course read-only.

Ideally, I want something like animal["Bear"] = 2, animal["Lion"] = 1, animal["Tiger"] = 1 etc.

Comment: What do you mean by _the "int" is of course read-only_?  If you have a `Dictionary<string,int>` then to add 1 to Bear you'd just do `dictionary["Bear"]++;`

Comment: I think it's difficult to give an answer when we have no idea how your animal classes are structured. Is there any form of abstraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
string[] animals = new string[] { "Bear", "Bear", "Lion", "Tiger", "Bear" };

var groups = animals.GroupBy(v => v);
foreach(var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}", group.Key, group.Count());
```

You can also make a Collection or List of Animals and get the count by its value type. Since it is not clear how your class looks like I have given example with the string.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to use Dictionary but the `int` is of course read-only.

`int` being a value type shouldn't stop you: you just need to treat it the way you treat immutable objects when you use them as dictionary values that need to change, i.e. by reassigning them.

Here is an example of how to increment a count inside a dictionary:

```
var counts = new Dictionary<Animal,int>();
Animal someAnimal = ... // Get some animal
int currentCount;
if (counts.TryGetValue(someAnimal, out currentCount)) {
    counts[someAnimal] = currentCount+1;
} else {
    counts.Add(someAnimal, 1);
}
```